# jHipster fails to generate Gateway Docker Images

Tags: docker, jhipster, microservices

jHipster fails to generate Gateway Docker Images.

I have successfully built the micorservice application, but while making the microservice gateway, I encounter an ERROR [karma] in Running 'gulp.js test --no-notification'. I have tried many hours to resolve but failed to find out the source of two errors:

1. [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn'.
2. at formatError (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)

Please anyone can help?

On Mac OSX 10.11.6, using jHipster 3.6.1, the the micorservice gateway is also done (JWT, SQL, MySQL, H2, HazelCast, ElasticSearch, International, Gatling and Protractor).

.........
AFter having done npm install and bower install, proceed to build docker images:

Emacs-MacBook-Pro:gateway Emac$ ./mvnw -Pprod package docker:build

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Gateway 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[INFO] Copying 17 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[INFO] Copying 17 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ gateway ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ gateway ---
[INFO] surefireArgLine set to -javaagent:/Users/Emac/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.7.201606060606/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/target/test-results/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) @ gateway ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Installing node version v4.4.7
[INFO] Unpacking /Users/Emac/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/4.4.7/node-4.4.7-darwin-x64.tar.gz into /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node/tmp
[INFO] Copying node binary from /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node/tmp/node-v4.4.7-darwin-x64/bin/node to /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node/node
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] Installing npm version 3.10.5
[INFO] Unpacking /Users/Emac/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/npm/3.10.5/npm-3.10.5.tar.gz into /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node/node_modules
[INFO] Installed npm locally.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway
[INFO] 
[INFO] > gateway@0.0.0 postinstall /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway
[INFO] > webdriver-manager update
[INFO] 
[INFO] [22:37:12] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
[INFO] [22:37:12] I/update - selenium standalone: v2.53.1 up to date
[INFO] [22:37:12] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22mac32.zip
[INFO] [22:37:13] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.22mac32.zip
[INFO] [22:37:14] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22
[INFO] [22:37:14] I/update - chromedriver: v2.22 up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:bower (bower install) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Running 'bower install --no-color' in /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:gulp (gulp build) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Running 'gulp.js build --no-notification' in /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway
[INFO] [22:38:18] Using gulpfile ~/microservices/gateway/gulpfile.js
[INFO] [22:38:18] Starting 'clean'...
[INFO] [22:38:18] Finished 'clean' after 7.82 ms
[INFO] [22:38:18] Starting 'build'...
[INFO] [22:38:18] Starting 'copy:i18n'...
[INFO] [22:38:18] Starting 'copy:fonts'...
[INFO] [22:38:18] Starting 'copy:common'...
[INFO] [22:38:18] Starting 'inject:vendor'...
[INFO] [22:38:19] Starting 'ngconstant:prod'...
[INFO] [22:38:19] Starting 'copy:languages'...
[INFO] [22:38:19] Finished 'ngconstant:prod' after 320 ms
[INFO] [22:38:19] Finished 'copy:languages' after 196 ms
[INFO] [22:38:19] Finished 'copy:common' after 415 ms
[INFO] [22:38:19] gulp-inject 23 files into index.html.
[INFO] [22:38:19] Finished 'inject:vendor' after 438 ms
[INFO] [22:38:19] Finished 'copy:fonts' after 516 ms
[INFO] [22:38:19] Finished 'copy:i18n' after 594 ms
[INFO] [22:38:19] Starting 'copy'...
[INFO] [22:38:19] Finished 'copy' after 19 μs
[INFO] [22:38:19] Starting 'inject:app'...
[INFO] [22:38:20] gulp-inject 103 files into index.html.
[INFO] [22:38:20] Finished 'inject:app' after 564 ms
[INFO] [22:38:20] Starting 'inject:troubleshoot'...
[INFO] [22:38:20] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
[INFO] [22:38:20] Finished 'inject:troubleshoot' after 51 ms
[INFO] [22:38:20] Starting 'images'...
[INFO] [22:38:20] Starting 'styles'...
[INFO] [22:38:20] Starting 'html'...
[INFO] [22:38:20] Starting 'copy:swagger'...
[INFO] [22:38:20] Starting 'copy:images'...
[INFO] [22:38:20] Finished 'copy:images' after 28 ms
[INFO] [22:38:20] Finished 'styles' after 70 ms
[INFO] [22:38:20] Finished 'html' after 726 ms
[INFO] [22:38:20] Finished 'copy:swagger' after 754 ms
[INFO] [22:38:21] gulp-imagemin: Minified 3 images (saved 0 B - 0%)
[INFO] [22:38:21] Finished 'images' after 1.49 s
[INFO] [22:38:21] Starting 'assets:prod'...
[INFO] [22:38:44] Finished 'assets:prod' after 23 s
[INFO] [22:38:44] Finished 'build' after 26 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 104 source files to /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/target/classes
[WARNING] /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/src/main/java/com/emodak/buji/gateway/responserewriting/SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilter.java: /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/src/main/java/com/emodak/buji/gateway/responserewriting/SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilter.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/src/main/java/com/emodak/buji/gateway/responserewriting/SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilter.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/src/main/java/com/emodak/buji/gateway/TokenRelayFilter.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/src/main/java/com/emodak/buji/gateway/TokenRelayFilter.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/target/test-classes
[WARNING] /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/src/test/java/com/emodak/buji/gateway/responserewriting/SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilterTest.java: /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/src/test/java/com/emodak/buji/gateway/responserewriting/SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilterTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/src/test/java/com/emodak/buji/gateway/responserewriting/SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilterTest.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
objc[46612]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Running com.emodak.buji.gateway.responserewriting.SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilterTest
2016-09-10 22:39:07.302  WARN   --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-09-10 22:39:08.537 DEBUG   --- [           main] c.e.b.g.r.SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilter : Swagger-docs: rewritten Base URL with correct micro-service route: /service1
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.437 sec - in com.emodak.buji.gateway.responserewriting.SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilterTest
Running com.emodak.buji.security.SecurityUtilsUnitTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.269 sec - in com.emodak.buji.security.SecurityUtilsUnitTest
Running com.emodak.buji.service.UserServiceIntTest

        ██  ██    ██  ████████  ███████    ██████  ████████  ████████  ███████
        ██  ██    ██     ██     ██    ██  ██          ██     ██        ██    ██
        ██  ████████     ██     ███████    █████      ██     ██████    ███████
  ██    ██  ██    ██     ██     ██             ██     ██     ██        ██   ██
   ██████   ██    ██  ████████  ██        ██████      ██     ████████  ██    ██

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2016-09-10 22:39:18.809  WARN 46612 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/gateway/default": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-09-10 22:39:18.853  INFO 46612 --- [           main] c.e.buji.service.UserServiceIntTest      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-10 22:39:24.098  WARN 46612 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-09-10 22:39:25.121 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.emodak.buji.config.AsyncConfiguration  : Creating Async Task Executor
2016-09-10 22:39:27.595 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.e.buji.config.MetricsConfiguration     : Registering JVM gauges
2016-09-10 22:39:27.650 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.e.buji.config.MetricsConfiguration     : Monitoring the datasource
2016-09-10 22:39:27.651 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.e.buji.config.MetricsConfiguration     : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2016-09-10 22:39:28.834 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.e.buji.config.DatabaseConfiguration    : Configuring Liquibase
2016-09-10 22:39:28.861 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.e.b.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase synchronously
2016-09-10 22:39:33.557 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.e.b.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Started Liquibase in 4695 ms
2016-09-10 22:39:33.952 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.emodak.buji.config.CacheConfiguration  : Configuring Hazelcast
2016-09-10 22:39:34.110 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.emodak.buji.config.CacheConfiguration  : Configuring Hazelcast clustering for instanceId: gateway
2016-09-10 22:39:34.347  WARN 46612 --- [           main] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6.1] Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses.
2016-09-10 22:39:45.031  INFO 46612 --- [           main] com.emodak.buji.GatewayApp               : Running with Spring profile(s) : []
2016-09-10 22:39:48.315  WARN 46612 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.env                    : [Cardiac] max file descriptors [10240] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
2016-09-10 22:40:00.397 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.e.b.c.e.IndexReinitializer             : ElasticSearch indexes reset in 12 ms
2016-09-10 22:40:11.100 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] c.emodak.buji.config.CacheConfiguration  : Starting HazelcastCacheManager
2016-09-10 22:40:20.884  WARN 46612 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-09-10 22:40:21.974  INFO 46612 --- [           main] c.e.buji.service.UserServiceIntTest      : Started UserServiceIntTest in 72.623 seconds (JVM running for 79.635)
Hibernate: select authority0_.name as name1_0_0_ from jhi_authority authority0_ where authority0_.name=?
Hibernate: insert into jhi_user (id, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date, activated, activation_key, email, first_name, lang_key, last_name, login, password_hash, reset_date, reset_key) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-09-10 22:40:23.482 DEBUG 46612 --- [           main] com.emodak.buji.service.UserService      : Created Information for User: User{login='johndoe', firstName='John', lastName='Doe', email='john.doe@localhost', activated='false', langKey='en-US', activationKey='80060923054997847003'}
......
Hibernate: select authoritie0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, authoritie0_.authority_name as authorit2_4_0_, authority1_.name as name1_0_1_ from jhi_user_authority authoritie0_ inner join jhi_authority authority1_ on authoritie0_.authority_name=authority1_.name where authoritie0_.user_id=?
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.317 sec - in com.emodak.buji.web.rest.UserResourceIntTest
2016-09-10 22:40:29.743  WARN 46612 --- [.ShutdownThread] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [192.168.11.5]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Terminating forcefully...
2016-09-10 22:40:30.287  WARN 46612 --- [       Thread-6] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-09-10 22:40:30.537  INFO 46612 --- [       Thread-6] c.emodak.buji.config.CacheConfiguration  : Closing Cache Manager

Results :

Tests run: 32, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:report (post-unit-test) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/target/test-results/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'Gateway' with 120 classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:gulp (gulp test) @ gateway ---
[INFO] Running 'gulp.js test --no-notification' in /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway
[INFO] [22:41:35] Using gulpfile ~/microservices/gateway/gulpfile.js
[INFO] [22:41:35] Starting 'inject:test'...
[INFO] [22:41:35] Starting 'ngconstant:dev'...
[INFO] [22:41:35] Finished 'ngconstant:dev' after 142 ms
[INFO] [22:41:35] gulp-inject 22 files into karma.conf.js.
[INFO] [22:41:35] Finished 'inject:test' after 655 ms
[INFO] [22:41:35] Starting 'test'...
[INFO] 10 09 2016 22:41:47.224:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.1.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
[INFO] 10 09 2016 22:41:47.287:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
[INFO] 10 09 2016 22:41:47.402:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS



[INFO] 10 09 2016 22:41:47.500:ERROR [karma]: { [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
[INFO] Error: spawn EACCES
[INFO]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)



[INFO]     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
[INFO]     at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
[INFO]     at Object._execCommand (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:63:21)
[INFO]     at Object._start (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/index.js:76:10)
[INFO]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/process.js:14:10)
[INFO]     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
[INFO]     at Object.emit (events.js:169:7)
[INFO]     at Object.start (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/karma/lib/launchers/base.js:42:10)
[INFO]     at Object.j (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/karma/lib/launcher.js:108:17)
[INFO]     at Object.setTimeout.bind.j (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/karma/node_modules/qjobs/qjobs.js:143:18)
[INFO]     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)



[INFO] [22:41:47] 'test' errored after 12 s
[INFO] [22:41:47] Error: 1
[INFO]     at formatError (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)



[INFO]     at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
[INFO]     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
[INFO]     at Gulp.emit (events.js:169:7)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
[INFO]     at /Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
[INFO]     at finish (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
[INFO]     at cb (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
[INFO]     at removeAllListeners (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:379:7)
[INFO]     at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/Emac/microservices/gateway/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:390:9)
[INFO]     at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
[INFO]     at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
[INFO]     at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
[INFO]     at emitCloseNT (net.js:1537:8)
[INFO]     at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:431:9)
[INFO]     at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 08:53 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-10T22:42:47+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 67M/314M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:gulp (gulp test) on project gateway: Failed to run task: 'gulp.js test --no-notification' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Emacs-MacBook-Pro:gateway Emac$

Thanks in advance, Sam8881

Answer (score 0):

for me (./mvnw -Pprod);

- I create new user (ubuntu / linux)
- I login to that user
- I run  ./mvnw -Pprod command
- problem solved (*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:gulp*)